# How to pass a variable string within the xpath to identify an element in Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, variables, xpath, css-selectors

How to pass a variable string within the xpath to identify an element in Selenium and Java?

Code trials:

```
System.out.println("Name:\n");
String name = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter the no. of messages:\n");
int count = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter what you want to send:\n");
String mess = sc.next(); 
System.out.println("Enter anything after you have scanned the QR");
String a = sc.next();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@title='Rinmay AEI']")).click();
```

I want my user input `name` String to be placed instead of 'Rinmay AEI'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the value of *title* attribute, make it a variable and and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println("Name:\n");
  String name = sc.nextLine();
  // other lines of code
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[title='" + name + "']")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println("Name:\n");
  String name = sc.nextLine();
  // other lines of code
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@title='" + name + "']")).click();
  ```